# How do I update the values in a pandas dataframe column until first occurance of a value in the same column?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have following dataframe -

```
              50d-200d  Regime  
Date                          
2017-02-22       NaN       0  
2017-02-23       NaN       0  
2017-02-24       NaN       0  
2017-02-27      0.52       1  
2017-02-28      0.92       1  
...
2017-04-04      0.39       1  
2017-04-05      0.16       1  
2017-04-06     -0.08      -1  
2017-04-07     -0.30      -1  
2017-04-10     -0.51      -1
...
2017-08-09     -1.15      -1  
2017-08-10     -0.52      -1  
2017-08-11      0.07       1  
2017-08-17      2.67       1
```

I want to modify this dataframe such that the "Regime" column values are set to 0 until the first occurance of "-1".  After that, I would like to leave the dataframe unmodified.  How would I achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for index value of first `-1` and then set `0`:

```
idx = df['Regime'].eq(-1).idxmax()
df.iloc[:df.index.get_loc(idx), df.columns.get_loc('Regime')] = 0
print (df)
            50d-200d  Regime
Date                        
2017-02-22       NaN       0
2017-02-23       NaN       0
2017-02-24       NaN       0
2017-02-27      0.52       0
2017-02-28      0.92       0
2017-04-04      0.39       0
2017-04-05      0.16       0
2017-04-06     -0.08      -1
2017-04-07     -0.30      -1
2017-04-10     -0.51      -1
2017-08-09     -1.15      -1
2017-08-10     -0.52      -1
2017-08-11      0.07       1
2017-08-17      2.67       1
```

And another solution for [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared), thanks you:

```
df.iloc[:df.Regime.eq(-1).values.argmax(), df.columns.get_loc('Regime')] = 0
```

Comment: no problem, only remove `()` from `print (df)` to `print df`

Comment: oops, sorry. i forget datetime index. Answer is edited.

Comment: That works!  If you don't mind why did you have to handle the datetime index differently?

Comment: Sorry, there was a bit bug. For select by values like datetimeindex is necessary use `loc`, for select by positions `iloc`. Here is necessary select by positions, because `df.loc[:df['Regime'].eq(-1).idxmax() , 'Regime'] = 0` remove last `-1` and replace by `0`

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`np.logical_and.accumulate`

```
df.assign(Regime=df.Regime.mask(np.logical_and.accumulate(df.Regime.ne(-1)), 0))

            50d-200d  Regime
Date                        
2017-02-22       NaN       0
2017-02-23       NaN       0
2017-02-24       NaN       0
2017-02-27      0.52       0
2017-02-28      0.92       0
2017-04-04      0.39       0
2017-04-05      0.16       0
2017-04-06     -0.08      -1
2017-04-07     -0.30      -1
2017-04-10     -0.51      -1
2017-08-09     -1.15      -1
2017-08-10     -0.52      -1
2017-08-11      0.07       1
2017-08-17      2.67       1
```

**Option 2**

```
df.assign(Regime=df.Regime.mask(df.Regime.ne(-1).cumprod().astype(bool), 0))

            50d-200d  Regime
Date                        
2017-02-22       NaN       0
2017-02-23       NaN       0
2017-02-24       NaN       0
2017-02-27      0.52       0
2017-02-28      0.92       0
2017-04-04      0.39       0
2017-04-05      0.16       0
2017-04-06     -0.08      -1
2017-04-07     -0.30      -1
2017-04-10     -0.51      -1
2017-08-09     -1.15      -1
2017-08-10     -0.52      -1
2017-08-11      0.07       1
2017-08-17      2.67       1
```